# NoMethodError : undefined method `employee_inventories' for #<Inventory:>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, collections

I created a helper method in application to DRY the code.

```
module InventoriesHelper
  def employee_inventory_select(employee_inventories)
    case @employee_inventories[:status]
      when 'ALLOTED'
        @employee_inventories[:allot_date] = Time.now.strftime('%F')
      when 'CANCELLED'
        @employee_inventories.inventory.update(is_available: true)
      when 'RETURN'
        @employee_inventories.inventory.update(is_available: true)
        @employee_inventories[:return_date] = Time.now.strftime('%F')
    end
  end
end
```

called this helper method in inventory controller

```
    def inventory_available_status
        @employee_inventories = EmployeeInventory.where(:inventory_id => params[:id]).first
        if @employee_inventories.update(employee_inventories_params)
          employee_inventory_status = employee_inventory_select(@employee_inventories)
          redirect_to inventories_path
        else
          render :action => :show
        end
    end
  def employee_inventories_params
    params.require(:employee_inventory).permit(:employee_id, :allot_date, :return_date, :status, :inventory_id)
  end
```

in view I have written down this

```
    <% if inventory.employee_inventories.any?{|e| e[:status] == 'REQUESTED'} %>
        <%= link_to 'Allot', inventory_available_status_inventory_path(inventory,   :employee_inventory => { :status => 'ALLOTED' }) %>
        <%= link_to 'Cancel', inventory_available_status_inventory_path(inventory, :employee_inventory => { :status => 'CANCELLED' }) %>
  <% elsif inventory.employee_inventories.any?{|e| e[:status] == 'ALLOTED'} %>
       <%= link_to 'Return', inventory_available_status_inventory_path(inventory, :employee_inventory => { :status => 'RETURN' }) %>
<% end %>
```

after running this code . the following error is coming:-

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `employee_inventories'
>   for #)

I am having has_many through association

```
class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees, through: :employee_inventories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employees
end

class EmployeeInventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :inventory
end
```

I don't understand what is the problem there ? please guide me
 thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a one to many association between `inventory` and `employee_inventories`?

Comment: No I have has_many through association

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: edited my code plz go through it

Comment: You need to add `has_many :employee_inventories` in your `Inventory` model. More info about [has_many through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: Please post the complete error log

Answer (score 0):

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `employee_inventories'
>   for #)

You need to add `has_many :employee_inventories` in your `Inventory` model.

```
class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employee_inventories
  has_many :employees, through: :employee_inventories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employees
end
```